# Reading intergers from a text file in c

Tags: c

I want to take input from a file to my c program. The input should consists of Numbers and characters thereafter i want to differentiate both of them. As fscanf returns 0 when it encounters a non integers, it not worthy of being used here, what to do?

Comment: Read in the text and parse it

Comment: `fscanf` retruns 0 if it hasn't managed to parse any of the fields you've asked it to... nothing to do _per se_ with integers or not.  You need to expand on what you mean by "differentiate both of them" ... just do something with numbers?  Do something different with strings and numbers?  Your best bet may be to read lines as strings and look at `atoi` and `strtol` to tell them apart.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    int num, status;
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    while(EOF!=(status = fscanf(fp, "%d", &num))){
        if(status == 1){
            printf("%d\n", num);
        } else { //if(status == 0){
            (void)fgetc(fp);//replace by @chux's suggestion
```

<del>int ch;
                while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp)) && ch != '-' && !isdigit(ch));
                if(ch == '-'){
                    int pch = fgetc(fp);
                    if(isdigit(pch)){
                        ungetc(pch, fp);
                        ungetc(ch, fp);
                    }
                } else {
                    ungetc(ch, fp);
                }</del>

```
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ungetc(pch, fp); ungetc(ch, fp);` Back-to-back calls to `ungetc()` may fail.  "One character of pushback is guaranteed. If the ungetc function is called too many times on the same stream without an intervening read or file positioning operation on that stream, the operation may fail." C11 §7.21.7.10 2

Comment: I think that if this fails, it is good to use the `ftell` and `fseek` or `fgetpos` and `fsetpos`, but I think it's all right perhaps.

Comment: Perhaps the else clause could be simply: `} else { fgetc(fp); }` and just throw away 1 `char`.  If more than 1 `char` needs to be thrown out, then it will get caught in the next loop.

Answer (score -1):

simply just read the file one by one character at a time and check the range of the value as we know the value in integer value of '0' to '9' is from 48 to 57, just check and use.
Hope it will helps you.